# Can charger which exploded damage a laptop

Tags: hp-laptop

Can a HP laptop be damaged if the charger exploded while it was plugged in? (the laptop was shut down it that moment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, damage to the laptop can occur because of a voltage spike at the moment of explosion. So yes, damage can occur.

You might be lucky (especially since the laptop was off),  and the event above did not occur or at a high enough level to damage anything.

You need to get a new charger and see if you can power the laptop up. Be ready that it may be beyond redemption.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly "exploded" inside the charger and if it caused some kind of surge into the power cable connected to the laptop and what kind of surge protection the charger has for it's output. Also depends on how the charger was connected (via a power plug, USB C etc.) what kind of surge protection the laptop has for its power input.

Lastly it depends on what kind of damage, if any, the surge did to the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes damage could occur to the computer and any connected devices could also be damaged.

If you was wearing wired headphones, there's a chance of electrocution but this is low.

Comment: This answer has already been given. Noting that OP clearly states the computer was turned off, your headphones info is not applicable. Avoid answering questions that are already answered unless you have significant new and relevant information to add that has not already been given.